# Factorization of a bilinear matrix-valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $F(u, v) = \sum_{i}\sum_j u_i v_i C_{ij}$ is a bilinear matrix-valued function,
where $C_{ij}$ are known matrices.

Is there a relatively easy way to factorize $F$ so that
the $u$ and $v$ variables are separated?  That is, to find matrices $A_i$ and $B_j$ such that
$F(u,v) = (\sum_i u_i A_i)(\sum_j v_j B_j)$.